# How to test an application that uses LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm in the process of integrating LinkedIn into my application, via their API. The problem is that I cannot test it.

In order to test it, I need a test user that is administrator of a company page. I cannot create a company page since my test user does not meet the [minimum requirements](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1594/~/requirements-for-adding-company-pages).

How have other users of the API solved this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick peruse of the documentation for company page administration on LinkedIn's developer website yields this:

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#testing

LinkedIn has a special test company that you can in your test cases for this exact purpose.

Comment: Hadn't found that. Thank you

Comment: this link is empty please check it.